# Getting Error on commented JSON lines on Neovim

Tags: json, typescript, vim, neovim, tsconfig

[image]

Editing tsconfig.json file my neovim is a nightmare. All the commented section for this json file is highlighted in red color. Its only for json files.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Just as the error says, [JSON](https://www.json.org) doesn't allow comments.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the auto-generated `tsconfig.json` is **not** a valid JSON file, it's [jsonc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html#tsconfig) ("JSON with comments").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` is not JSON. It is actually the poorly specified ["JSON with Comments"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments) or "JSONC", a variant of JSON created by Microsoft for their tooling.

Unfortunately, Microsoft uses the `.json` extension for its JSONC files so editors where filetype is assigned based on the extension incorrectly assume the file is JSON. Vim actually supports JSONC but only for files with the `.jsonc` extension. Bummer.

Options…

1. Change the filetype manually:

   ```
   :set filetype=jsonc
   ```

   [image: manual]
2. Add a `:help modeline` to your JSONC files:

   ```
   // vim: filetype=jsonc
   ```

   [image: modeline]
3. Set up proper filetype detection by putting [this file](https://github.com/kevinoid/vim-jsonc/blob/master/ftdetect/jsonc.vim) under `~/.vim/ftdetect/`, as per [this document](https://github.com/kevinoid/vim-jsonc/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Also, I am not sure if it is your prettier plugin or your colorscheme that is broken, but showing all the errors as red on red is indeed nightmarish. There is much to do beyond fixing that JSON/JSONC mess.